# How can I update a Json Object using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Hi all, i am concatenating a `JSON` string like this:

```
      var addresses = "[";

         addresses += '{"AddressID":' + adressid + ',"EmailID":' + $('#txtemailData').val() + ',"Hno":' + $('#txthno').val() + ',"StreetName":' + $('#txtstreetname').val() + ',"City":' + $('#txtcity').val() + ',"StateID":' + $('#ddlState').val() + ',"CountryID":' + $('#ddlcountry').val() + ',"Zip":' + $('#txtzip').val() + ',"PhoneNumber":' + $('#txtphonenumber').val() + ',"Fax":' + $('#txtfax').val() + ',"AddressName:' + $('#txtaddresstype').val() + '"},';
```

And the object looks like this:

```
[{
   "AddressID":2,
   "EmailID":akanilkumar443@gmail.com,
   "Hno":Hyderabad,
   "StreetName":Gachibowli,
   "City":Hyderabad,
   "StateID":1,
   "CountryID":1,
   "Zip":040,
   "PhoneNumber":8341516166,
   "Fax":23123131,
   "AddressName:Store Address"},
 { 
   "AddressID":3,
   "EmailID":akanilkumar443@gmail.com,
   "Hno":aSAs,
   "StreetName":asdasdad,
   "City":asdasda,
   "StateID":1,
   "CountryID":1,
   "Zip":asdasda,
   "PhoneNumber":asdasda,
   "Fax":asdasda,
"AddressName:Store Type"
}]
```

How can I update this particular value of json object based on it's id?

Suppose I want to change some of the values of my object
where `AddressID=2`. For example, I want to change the `EmailID`,`Streetname` of `JSON` objects where `AddressID=2`. How can I do this using jQuery?

I am trying it like this, but it's not going in the loop, Can any one help me here please?

```
    function EditAddress(addressid) {
    alert(addressid);
    alert(addresses);
    var addressobject =JSON.parse(addresses.substring(0, addresses.length - 1) + ']');
    jQuery.each(addressobject, function (i, val) {
        alert(val.AddressID);
        if (val.AddressID == addressid) 
        {
            //update logic
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Why built a JSON string manually, if you want to use the object?

Comment: Did I just notice a ninja spammer around here?

Comment: The JSON you are creating is not valid JSON. No JSON parser will be able to parse that, let alone modify.

Comment: I'm not certain what context this code is in... but if you are trying to manipulate JSON data and it's a frequent occurrence, might I suggest using a client side MVC framework like http://backbonejs.org ?

Comment: do you need an array? or could another collection fit the purpose?

Answer (score 3):

You can just loop through the array `arr` using the [`$.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) function, then search for where `id` property value is `2`. If found then update the required property in the object `obj` and then break out of the loop like:

```js
var arr = [
    {"id": 1, "name": "Apple"  , "isVisible": false},
    {"id": 2, "name": "Orange", "isVisible": false},
    {"id": 3, "name": "Banana", "isVisible": false}
]

$.each( arr, function( i, obj ) {
  if(obj.id === 2){
    console.log("Current " + obj.id + " = " + obj.isVisible);
    obj.isVisible = true;
    console.log("Changed " + obj.id + " = " + obj.isVisible);
    return false; // Loop will stop running after this
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly don't create the string by hand. It's a lot more robust to use build-in features so do this:

```
var addressesAsArray = [],
    addressAsObject = {}
    address;
//assuming some loop or other
address = {
              "AddressID": adressid,
              "EmailID":$('#txtemailData').val(),
              "Hno":$('#txthno').val(),
              "StreetName": $('#txtstreetname').val(),
              "City": $('#txtcity').val(),
              "StateID": $('#ddlState').val(),
              "CountryID": $('#ddlcountry').val(),
              "Zip": $('#txtzip').val(),
              "PhoneNumber": $('#txtphonenumber').val(),
              "Fax": $('#txtfax').val(),
              "AddressName": $('#txtaddresstype').val()
          };
addressesAsArray.push(address);
addressAsObject[address.AddressID] = address;
```

if you need to find an address with a given ID the approach would depend on whether you are looking in addressesAsArray or in addressesAsObject. The latter is straight forward

```
address = addressesAsObject[addressIDBeingSought];
```

in the array case you can simply loop

```
for(i = 0, len = addressesAsArray.length;i<len; i += 1){
   if(addressesAsArray[i].AddressID === addressIDBeingSought) {
       address = addressesAsArray[i];
       break;
   }
}
```

when you are done with the updating you can then get that as JSON by

```
json = JSON.stringify(adresses);
```

Answer (score -1):

use linq.js javascript library or jquery plugin: http://linqjs.codeplex.com/

```
    <!DOCTYPE>
    <html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="linq.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <script>  
    var array = [{
       AddressID:2,
       EmailID:'akanilkumar443@gmail.com',
       Hno:'Hyderabad'
       },
     { 
       AddressID:3,
       EmailID:'akanilkumar443@gmail.com',
       Hno:'aSAs'
    }];
    Enumerable.From(array).Where("$.AddressID == 3").ToArray()[0].Hno= 'ololo'; 
// or this: 
// Enumerable.From(array).Where(function(x){return x.AddressID == 3}).ToArray()[0].Hno= 'ololo'; 
    alert(array[1].Hno)  
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```